# check in local workspace into new git repo

Tags: java, eclipse, git, github

I have a local workspace which I want to save in git, this wasnt a local git repo until now.Just workspace 
The steps I did in git bash

cd myworkspace

git init

git add .

git commit -m "First commit"

git remote add origin https://github.com/username/eclipse.git

git push origin master

By doing this I got an error

```
! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/username/eclipse.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

then I did this

git pull origin master

```
warning: no common commits
remote: Counting objects: 4, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (3/3), done.
remote: Total 4 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
Unpacking objects: 100% (4/4), done.
From https://github.com/koushikpaul1/eclipse
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
 * [new branch]      master     -> origin/master
fatal: refusing to merge unrelated histories
```

Anyone can help me with this error ,

Note : I created my git repo as a java one so currently it has only 
.gitignore and README.md

while googling I found the steps to check in an existing workspace into git are

$ cd my_project

$ git init

$ git add *

$ git commit -m "First commit"

$ git remote add origin https://github.com/yourname/my_project.git

$ git pull origin master

$ git push origin master

But I am stuck at the second last step.

Many Thanks !

Comment: Did you try pulling from the URL instead or origin?

Comment: open the git configuration and check that origin is actually the url you are using...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here is you already init repository on your local workspace which already contain some files. When you create repository on GitHub and init it with .gitignore and README.md it also contain some files.

When you push your project git will reject because it does not know how to merge your content.

Here are solutions

1. Use git push -f which will *push* all your local repository to remote repository but this will also replace .gitignore and README.md, then you can them manually later.
2. Delete your remote git repository and reinit it as bare repository (do not check init with .gitignore, README.md) then try to push again.
3. Just clone remote repository to your local workspace then manually add your files to the cloned repository

For more info visit:
https://help.github.com/articles/creating-a-new-repository/

See number 5.

> There are a number of optional items you can pre-populate your
>   repository with. **If you're importing an existing repository to GitHub,
>   don't choose any of these options, as you may introduce a merge
>   conflict.** You can choose to add these files from the command line
>   later.
>
> You can create a README, which is a document describing your project.
>   You can create a .gitignore file, which is a set of ignore rules.
>
> You can choose to add a software license for your project.

Comment: The solution became easy after you correctly pointed the reason , Thanks a lot . Worked like a charm. Another help I will ask that gitignore works perfectly when I use gitbash, but while using eclipse git plugin, even if I add the patterns in the [eclipse] : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38167476/gitignore-not-working-with-eclipse